# Python output to command prompt (and at all) stopped working

Tags: windows, output, command-line-interface, python-3.7

## Summary

I used to get output from all the print statements, and my Python script would run as expected, now I run it normally, if line feeds the command prompt, wait about 3-5 seconds, and then display a new line with the command prompt. This happened as I was making additions to the test suite and data sets I was given.

## Details

I'm making a Python 3.7 machine learning test suite on a Windows machine for my boss and was making pretty great headway when the output of my python script stopped working. I've searched the inter-webs and have not found situations like mine with any solutions, most problems arise from people not writing their scripts properly.

When I run the script in command prompt, I run it with "py myscript.py {args}" or "python myscript.py {args}". I have also tried with a -3 and -3.7 Python option.

My debugging of this problem is as follows:
**-** Added a print statement at the beginning of main: no print output
**-** Changed the instantiation name of a variable that is required later while keeping the use of that variable the same: no error output
**-** Uninstalled argparse (which is used in the script) using pip uninstall: no error output
**-** Created a separate Python script that only has a single print statement in main: no output
**-** Running python –V: outputs “Python 3.7.2”
**-** Changing or completely removing the #! line at the top of the file: no difference

I only have Python 3.7 installed on the computer I am working on. I also installed Visual Studio Code(VSC) and the respective Python module for VSC, and the Python script runs perfectly there when run under VSC's run with (or without) debugging. I tried to run it through VCS's terminals, and the output is missing there as well.

The included code is a small subset of the program that should answer most of the immediate questions. Am I just missing something?

```
#!python3.7
.
. (import statements)
.
def main():
  print ('Python Output Test\n')
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-s', '--seed', type=int, default=42, help='Set the seed for the algorithms.')
  parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', default=False, action="store_true", help='Use when lots of output is not necessary.')
  parser.add_argument('-r', '--run', type=int, default=0, choices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], help='Use to determine which file to use.')
  args = parser.parse_args()

  seed = args.seed
  quiet = args.quiet
  runType = args.run

  print ('MachineLearning.py -s ', seed, ' -r ', runType)
.
. (lots of code that used to work)
.
return 0

if __name__ is "__main__":
  main()
```

The above code should output those print statements to the command prompt, or maybe errors should be reported if there are errors, but I'm getting ***nothing***.

Comment: The one thing I forgot to include! I'm running the command with "py myscript.py {args}" and with "python myscript.py {args}". I've also tried forcing a -3 or -3.7 and those don't output either.

Comment: @eryksun When I right click the file and Open with... -> Python, it does not print to the Python window, and checking file associations in Windows 10 Settings shows Python being associated with .py files. However when I check in command prompt both ftype and assoc do not have entries for Python files: is that what you meant when bringing up file associations?

As for removing the imports and running: it gives the same functionality, just with less of a delay before bringing up the next command prompt...

Comment: If you're running py.exe or python.exe directly from an existing shell and inheriting its console, then it's not a file-association problem. (FYI, CMD's `assoc` and `ftype` built-in commands are not generally useful nowadays. They only report the classic per-machine associations as were used in NT 4. Use Explorer to manage file associations.) Are you using an alternate console such as ConEmu? If so make sure to test this with just a plain console. If it still doesn't work, enable the console's legacy mode in its properties (Alt+Space, P) and try again from a new shell opened from Explorer.

Comment: Also try running `python -I myscript.py` and `python -IS myscript.py` to isolate from environment variables and site module customization.

Comment: Running with the `python -i myscript.py` did work, through I now need to figure out why the script works only in this mode: potentially an issue in the PYTHONSTARTUP file? Thank you so much for your help in getting this workaround for me!